# Why is AWS Lambda taking 3+ seconds to load aws-sdk package?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, shopify, webhooks

When writing a Lambda function which utilizes the aws-sdk NodeJS package for a Shopify webhook, I noticed that the require statement for the package is taking over 3 seconds to load.  This is causing issues because Shopify requires a response from its webhooks within 5 seconds.  I abstracted the code out of my function to test it by itself and received the same results:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const start = new Date().getTime();
  console.log('start: '+ new Date())
  require('aws-sdk');
  console.log('end:' + new Date())
  const end  = new Date().getTime();
  console.log('length: ' + (end - start) + 'ms');
  callback();
}
```

Here was the output:

```
START RequestId: Version: $LATEST
2017-11-30T13:23:57.506Z        start: Thu Nov 30 2017 13:23:57 GMT+0000 (UTC)
END RequestId: 
REPORT RequestId:   Duration: 3001.29 ms    Billed Duration: 3000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB    Max Memory Used: 31 MB  
2017-11-30T13:24:00.499Z  Task timed out after 3.00 seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue appears to be that I was not giving the Lambda function enough memory to load in the package. I increased the memory with the following results:

- 512MB brought it down to 1000ms
- 1GB brought it down to 500ms

Comment: The CPU capacity allocated to your containers is proportional to the amount of memory you allocate.  It isn't really the amount of memory, since you only peaked at 31 MB.  The big problem here is that you shouldn't be doing this inside the handler function.  Move it into the global space above the handler so that it only needs to execute when containers are created, not with each invocation.

Comment: Well that makes a lot more sense, I was not aware CPU and memory were correlated.  
Also smart with moving the require to global space, not sure how I missed that.